# Not getting folders in Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

With Postman (standalone app) I try to get the folders from a SP Online list.

So

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/DocStorage/_api/lists/getbytitle('Demo')
```

properly returns the data of the list. However, getting its folders via

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/DocStorage/_api/lists/getbytitle('Demo')/RootFolder/Folders
```

returns an empty result:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": []
}
```

Trying to access a folder in that list directly, such as:

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/DocStorage/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/DocStorage/Demo/aFolderName')
```

comes back with 403 Access denied.

I believe the two problems are related and it's most likely an authorization problem. However, there is a valid token sent along with above requests, and the client app is configured with fullControl rights on the SP online site:

[Site.FullControl.All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9XGW.png)

So, I wonder why I'm able to access the list ('Demo') but not its folders.